# Add a padding to placeholder when label also inside input

Tags: html, css, padding, placeholder

I have an input with label inside. I need to increase padding from label to placeholder (difference maybe 3 or 5 px). What should I do?

I've already tried adding `padding-bottom` to label placeholder and also `padding-top` to placeholder. It didn't work. Maybe because of the positioning of blocks.

If you knew how to solve this problem, I'd like to see.

```css
.form-control {
  width: 320px;  
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control input {
  display: blocl;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fcc;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #500;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-control label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 18px;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}


.form-control input:valid + label,
.form-control input:focus + label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-control">
    <input type="text" id="login" required>
    <label for="login">Login</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `display: blocl;` is it a typo? Did you mean `block`?

Comment: yep it is "block". but it doesn't matter here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder text will always sit in the center within an input. To achieve more spacing between the label and the placeholder text, what you would need to do is that you add a `padding-top` value which is greater than `padding-bottom` of your input. I have set `20px` and `10px` respectively which would effectively increase the spacing b/w label and placeholder by `5px`.

```css
.form-control {
  width: 320px;  
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

.form-control input {
  display: block;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fcc;
  padding: 20px 15px 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #500;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form-control label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  top: 18px;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: .2s;
}


.form-control input:valid + label,
.form-control input:focus + label {
  top: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-control">
    <input type="text" id="login" required>
    <label for="login">Login</label>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```